# $loader = new loader($registry) classloader' not found in

Tags: php, loader

i am have a php code in openCard. 
i higher version php to up 5.6 but i have this error if open site:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Loader' not found in
>
> /homepages/30/d672723767/htdocs/koolergazi.com/index.php:38 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /homepages/30/d672723767/htdocs/koolergazi.com/index.php on line 38

in line 38 have this code:

```
    // Loader
$thread = new MyThread($loader)
$loader = new Loader($registry);
$registry->set('load', $loader);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is on line 38.

Before that, you should either have a bunch of `require_once` statements, like this:

```
require_once 'includes/some-lib/SomeClass.php';
```

Or, you should be loading an autoloader like composer:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

You didn't load the class definition file for Loader, so when you call `new Loader($registry)` the code fails. Just require in all the classes you need. I recommend composer, since it's a one line solution.

Comment: tanks for your answer.Insert this line to index.php?

Comment: Yes. Find out what folder the class is in, and require it before the new call

Comment: I insert this code :{:require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'engine/loader.php');} and get this error:Error: Could not load database file mysql!

Comment: looks like you need to find THAT class and require it too. Pain in the ass eh? That's why I love composer. One require_once, and everything just autoloads after that.